# Achieving a "Soft" open mechanism

Tags: mechanical-engineering

How do those mechanisms such as the ones in cars work - when you open a tray or glove-box, and it opens slowly by "easing in".

I would like to build my own compartment with a sliding cover that would slowly open by with the push of a button.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is they use a piston/ cylinder arrangement that has a small hole to allow the air in / out to slow down the rate of movement caused by the weight or a spring .

As for a name : damper or damping piston comes to mind.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a specific name for these pistons?